# combing regexes into optional groups

Tags: regex, django-urls

I have 4 regexes which are currently working, but I want to combine them into 1 regex because there are a lot of similar elements and it is probably better practice. This is in django urls.py

```
url(r'^news/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)/[0-9]+/attachment/[0-9]+/$',                
url(r'^news/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/$',
url(r'^news/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)/[0-9]+/$',
url(r'^news/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)/$',
```

This is my attempt, but it only matches the first two.

```
^news/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+/(attachment/[0-9]+|[0-9]+)?)?/$
```

Edit:
Examples of each regex

```
/news/some-slug/1231/attachment/1231
/news/some-slug/123121/1231/
/news/some-slug/1312/
/news/some-slug/
```

And don't match any other patterns.

EDIT: updated my attempt, getting closer, just not sure why the ? isnt making the groups optional as it should

testing on http://www.pyregex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the options:

```
^news/(?P<slug>.+)/([0-9]+/(attachment/([0-9]+/)?)?)?$
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/5D1IDMijkS)

Comment: Just tried that, it still only matches the last one. I've added one example of each regex to description

Comment: @stray it works for me. see demo link. also, your examples are not the same as your original question - they have `"..."` at the front, so the demo link uses `.*` at the front to mimic "anything" at the start. Other than that all  your samples match with the original regex.

Comment: fiddled round with that a bit, final working version is
^news/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+/(attachment/[0-9]+/|[0-9]+/)?)?$
thanks.

Slug should have not been .+ and needed to use a |